# How can I import using sqoop by joining on a file that is already present in HDFS?

Tags: hive, sqoop

I have some IDs based on which I want to import data using sqoop into the Hive. But the number of IDs are too high to be given manually. How can I perform this action with minimal effort?

Any guidance would be very much appreciated.
Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

SQOOP cannot read the list of values from a file.

The best option is to write a Shell script which reads the list of values and produces the SQOOP command in flight  using the values read and executes it.